# How can I connect to Postgres running in a Docker container on a non-default port from the command line?

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-compose, psql

I am new to Docker, and even after reading several similar questions on Stack Overflow do not really understand what I need to do to connect to Postgres using `psql` via the command line. My Postgres container is running on port 6432, mapped to the default port of 5432 (I changed the default port because I also have the Postgres desktop app running with other databases on port 5432).

I have tried `psql -p 6432` but I keep getting this error: `psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`. I then tried `psql -h localhost -p 6432 -U root`, and was prompted to put in the password for the root user, which failed even though I input the correct password and produced this error: `psql: error: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist`. I know that my Postgres container is running because I can see it running in the Docker desktop app.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

networks: 
    my_test_app:

services: 

    # nginx
    nginx-service:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx-container
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        volumes: 
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on: 
            - php-service
            - postgres-service
        networks: 
            - my_test_app 
  
    # php
    php-service:
        image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
        container_name: php-container
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        working_dir: /var/www/project
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
        networks: 
            - my_test_app  

    # postgres
    postgres-service:
        image: postgres:alpine
        container_name: postgres-container
        ports: 
            - "6432:5432"
        volumes: 
            - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: root
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
            POSTGRES_DB: db_my_test_app
        networks: 
            - my_test_app
```

...and my nginx config file (I have no idea if this is relevant):

```
server {

    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-service:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you may be able to offer me. By the way, is there any way that I can view and edit the databases (create/alter tables, etc.) I create in this container using a service like Postico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to connect to a different database than the one that actually exists.

You specify an environment variable in your config:

```
POSTGRES_DB: db_my_test_app
```

When this postgres container starts up and finds an empty data directory, it creates a database for you. It determines the name of that new database based on a few checks. In order:

1. What is the value of `$POSTGRES_DB`, if it is set
2. What is the value of `$POSTGRES_USER, if it is set
3. If nothing else, call it 'postgres'

When `psql` connects to postgres, it has to connect to a database. Unless a different one is specified, it tries to connect to a database with the same name as the user that is connecting.

Given your command: `psql -h localhost -p 6432 -U root`, psql will try and connect to a database called `root`. When it finds that this database doesn't exist, it prints the following:

```
❯ psql -h localhost -p 6432 -U root
Password for user root:
psql: error: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist
```

If we specify a database name to match the one that's configured in your docker-compose configuration, we get the following:

```
✖2 ❯ psql -h localhost -p 6432 -U root -d db_my_test_app
Password for user root:
psql (13.2)
Type "help" for help.

db_my_test_app=#
```

Your quick fix is to specify `-d <database_name>` when you try to connect.

If you'd like to change the name of this database, the bit about "postgres creates a database only if it finds an empty data directory" becomes important: since you specify a docker volume `./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, your database files will be persisted between docker compose sessions and you'll need to delete the `./postgres` directory on your host machine to clear it out and create a new one.

As an aside, since your initial question states that `psql` is unable to connect to postgres, I think it'll be helpful to show what that error message looks like as well:

```
❯ psql -h localhost -p 9876
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 9876?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 9876?
```